# string sleuth messages in a NoSql store

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I would like to store the spring cloud sleuth messages that come in my zipkin server (ala @EnableZipkinStreamServer) into a NoSql store.

I know that the original zipkin impl used cassandra which would work for me but I am curious about say MongoDb or CouchBase.

I looked in the documents (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_zipkin_consumer) and saw that you can use spring-boot-starter-jdbc for this and it will write into the MySQL DB instance that you define.

I don't see an API/SPI for putting this into anything else.  Is there one and what is it.  I can implement the NoSql portion myself.

Comment: ok, I found this library from the openzipkin project that represents the mysql impl https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage/mysql.  It seems to match what the spring cloud sleuth project pulled in when i opened the project in intellij

Comment: following on my previous comment I see that this "may be" the supported implements in various stores?   https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage.  Now, how would I tie these into the spring cloud sleuth project?

Comment: ok I found the library zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-mysql-1.6.0.jar which is where the "zipkin.storage.type" is read and connected.  I am assuming that nothing was done for the other zipkin-storage types of cassandra and elasticsearch?

Comment: looks like this library is set in the spring-cloud-sleuth-dependencies pom and the spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream pom.  I suppose one could create a new zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-cassandra and a new zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch but put the following property in each@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "zipkin.storage.type", havingValue = "xxx") where xxx is the storage type. Yes?

Comment: I found the two other libraries for elasticsearch and cassandra autoconfigure so I will try to add them to my build and use zipkin.storage.type=cassandra and see if it works

Comment: In case of any questions you can try to ask at The Zipkin Gitter - https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin . Maybe someone has already done sth similar